# Can I use Cloudflare to look like multiple websites from one website?

Tags: cloudflare

I'm a Cloudflare noob.  I have had one site up and running for a while as a way of doing https for my site.  I host it on http://www.pishandtish.com (made up name for this example) and through the joys of Cloudflare the world sees it as https://www.pishandtish.com - around the back, Cloudflare is fetching the content from my http://www.pishandtish.com site and proxying it to the world as https://www.pishandtish.com

Pretty straightforward stuff - Cloudflare is proxying my content.

But if, say, I had http://foo.pishandtish.com and http://bar.pishandtish.com, could I use Cloudflare for the rest of the world to see my http://foo.pishandtish.com as https://foo.com, and my http://bar.pishandtish.com as https://bar.com ?  (i.e. a way of a cheapskate to do two websites on a single-website hosting plan)

And if so, any clues as to how?  Some sort of request rewriting? And can I do it on the free Cloudflare plan?

These are just for very small (zero budget) community groups, and very-low-traffic sites.

Answer (score 1):

OK, what I think you'd need here is for Cloudflare to re-write the Host header of the http request, so that my request for something from foo.com looks like a request for foo.pishandtish.com by the time it arrives at my website (proxied and host-header-rewritten by Cloudflare).

Host-rewriting is a feature for domains on the Cloudflare Enterprise plan.
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206652947-Using-Page-Rules-to-Re-Write-Host-Headers